# Mysql insert multiple rows if each not between 2 column range?

Tags: mysql

Using PHP I dynamically generate multiple values and insert them into a table, simplified example of an insert with some values:

```
INSERT INTO table (time1,time2)
VALUES ('08:00','09:00'),('09:00','10:00'),('11:00','12:00');
```

With the above example, I'd like to prevent this from inserting:

```
INSERT INTO table (time1,time2)
    VALUES ('08:15','08:45'),('09:30','12:00');
```

Is it possible to make a range comparison between 2 columns when inserting multiple values? Or would I need to make a loop with single inserts (which I'd like to avoid for performance reasons)?

EDIT: I'm submitting the data by form with PHP. I guess the logical step is to use $_POST values and do a SELECT checking if the times conflict. Whether to use BETWEEN in SELECT or return all values back for a PHP function is another matter.

Comment: **Why?** Why put all burden on mysql? Check this in php, besides you can't put a WHERE clause on insert statement.

Comment: First of all, what is the datatype of these columns in your database? The simplified example makes it look like you are using strings to register times. That will make it hard to compare anything.

Comment: @AsheraH I'm using TIME as the datatype

Comment: @Shaharyar Oh, you mean pull all the data and PHP compute? I just thought there was a simpler sql option for comparison

Comment: You said you're generating data in php, so why not perform that comparison in php and insert the final and proper dataset in mysql. But if you still want to do it in mysql, you can use `insert before trigger` to check what is going to insert and prevent it. But I wouldn't recommend this because of its cost.

Comment: I guess I wasn't specific enough, apologies. I'm actually filling the data by form and would like to avoid conflicting values. So my thinking now is to use an if check which calls for a SELECT that checks the $_POST values. Now the question is whether I should do the range comparison on that SELECT or in my code.

Comment: Oh, in that case you definitely need to query mysql and check if the range is valid or not. So a/c to your first insertion, the correct range should be `12:00 - 13:00` rather than the 2 you wrote in the 2nd query?

Comment: Yes the newly inserted range shouldn't be between existing ranges

Comment: @Shaharyar do you think all the PHP to mysql has no cost and is magically free?

Comment: @Drew Did you even read the whole conversation?

Comment: Sadly yes I did

Comment: Then you probably misunderstood something, OP's explanation was a bit confusing that's why I asked him to perform all calculation in php.

Comment: I would never do that. But then again I profile everything.

Answer (score 0):

Check for indivisual entries form php, use this query to check the number of conflicts the new entry is making:

```
SELECT count(*) as `conflicts` 
    FROM table 
WHERE 
    '08:15' BETWEEN time1 AND time2 -- user your variable here
    OR
    '08:45' BETWEEN time1 AND time2 -- user your variable here
```